# Bound of a sublinear function defined using lim sup

Tags: functional-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

In my functional analysis course, we defined the sublinear function on $l^{\infty}_{\mathbb{R}}$: $$p(x)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k .$$
What I don't get is why we have: $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$, $$p(x)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n-m+1}\sum_{k=m}^n x_k$$ and why that implies $p(x)\in[\inf\limits_{k\geq m}x_k, \sup\limits_{k\geq m}x_k]$

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional analysis specifically. The point is, starting the sum from a higher up index won't affect the limsup. The implication that $p(x) \in [\inf_{k \ge m} x_k, \sup_{k \ge m} x_k]$ is immediate since $\frac{1}{n-m+1}\sum_{k=m}^n x_k \in [\inf_{k \ge m} x_k, \sup_{k \ge m} x_k]$ for each $n \ge m$.

Comment: Precisely, the way I tried to show what is needed is by shifting, but then I just get: 
$$p(x)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n-m+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} x_k+\sum_{k=m}^{n-m+1} x_k\right).$$  
Then, if I could split the limsup, I'd be done. But the limsup is only subadditive, that's where I'm stuck.
For the second part, I admit that it was immediate, I kinda screwed up :p

Comment: the limsup is subadditive in general, but a crucial fact is the following: If $(b_n)_n$ is an arbitrary sequence of reals and $(a_n)_n$ converges to some number $L$, then $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n+b_n = L+\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered by mathworker21.

In particular, the first assertion follows from the equality
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} x_k
+ \frac{n-m+1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n-m+1}\sum_{k=m}^n x_k.
$$

At r.h.s., as $n\to +\infty$ (and keeping $m$ fixed) the first summation goes to $0$, whereas
$\frac{n-m+1}{n} \to 1$.